# pandas for python creates multiple index columns when saving df in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

When I iterate this code over, pandas keeps creating new index columns in my csv.

```
import pandas as pd

credentials = pd.read_csv("credentials.csv")

email = "jarda@yahoo.cz"
nick = "jarda"
passw = "heslo"
csfd_conf_link = "test.link"

dict_to_append = {"nick": nick, "pass": passw, "email": email, "conf_link": csfd_conf_link}

credentials_updated = credentials.append(dict_to_append, ignore_index=True)
credentials_updated.to_csv("credentials.csv")
```

So it ends up looking like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0FNQ.png) (better visible in the screenshot):

```
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1  ...                         email                                          conf_link
0           0           0.0  ...                adam@seznam.cz                                               test
1           1           1.0  ...                 pepa@gmail.cz                                               test
2           2           2.0  ...  philbake.da.murt.l@gmail.com  https://www.csfd.cz/potvrzeni/registration/?co...
3           3           3.0  ...                jarda@yahoo.cz                                          test.link
4           4           4.0  ...                jarda@yahoo.cz                                          test.link
5           5           5.0  ...                jarda@yahoo.cz                                          test.link
6           6           NaN  ...                jarda@yahoo.cz                                          test.link
```

I know that indexing can be turned of with `credentials_updated.to_csv("credentials.csv", index=False)`. However, what if I wanted to have the columns indexed?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The multiple index columns appear *only* in the CSV output? Please provide a [mcve]. _better visible in the screenshot_ You should share the actual CSV, it's clearer and more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `Index` roundtrip, you can specify `index_col` in your call to pd.read_csv, and keep `index=True` in your call to `to_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    credentials = pd.read_csv("credentials.csv", index_col=0)
except FileNotFoundError:
    credentials = pd.DataFrame()
...

credentials_updated.to_csv("credentials.csv")
```

The try/except will help you out if you delete your `"credentials.csv"` for whatever reason.

Comment: To expand a bit on *why* this is the solution: You are currently reading in the csv without specifying that there is already an index column. So each time you read it in it is making a new index column.